# Why won't my solution work to find minimum depth of a binary tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, binary-search-tree

I don't understand how my solution for finding minimum depth of a binary tree doesn't work?  What am I doing wrong?

Here's a link to the problem if you're curious: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-depth-of-binary-tree/submissions/

```
public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
    if(root == null) return 0;

    int left = minDepth(root.left);
    int right = minDepth(root.right);

    int ans = Math.min(left, right) + 1;

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example where the code does not work?  Your logic looks correct to me; at least running it manually with a few cases all seems to work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hey Tim, I don't quite understand what you mean by that :o.  Leetcode isn't accepting my answer.

Comment: Try [1,2,3,4,5,6], the outcome of your code is different as expected. You need to consider the no of node from root to "leaf".

Comment: @samabcde yeah I tried [1,2,3,4,5,6] and it works just fine.  I don't know why leetcodes default test case doesn't work for me though

Comment: I see "your answer is 2" but "expected is 3" for [1,2,3,4,5,6].

Comment: @samabcde woops, my apologies!! I saw the green "finished" word and thought it was accepted.  I've been going at this for a while, I'm starting to lose my marbles haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will not work in the case only one side is *null*, like

```
  3
 / \
   20
  /  \
 15   7
```

as it will return 1 (while `3` is not a leaf).

You need to test if one side is *null*, ignore it and deal with the other side

Comment: waiiiiit, I think I understand what to do now!! Thank you for the hint.