# Find minimum depth of binary tree solution does not work when one side of tree is null

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

I am trying to understand why my solution to find the minimum depth of binary tree does not work when one side of the tree is `None`.

There's already a question asked on this here - [Why won't my solution work to find minimum depth of a binary tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803500/why-wont-my-solution-work-to-find-minimum-depth-of-a-binary-tree) but the answer there still does not make me understand.

My implementation code is as below.

```
class Solution:
    def minDepth(self, root: 'TreeNode') -> 'int':
        if root is None:
            return 0

        left = self.minDepth(root.left)
        right = self.minDepth(root.right)

        min_depth = min(left, right)

        return 1 + min_depth
```

When the last line is modified to the following, it works.

```
    if left == 0 or right == 0:
        return 1 + left + right

    return 1 + min_depth
```

My question is, why do you need to check if one side is `None` or not if in the end, you sum them all up anyway - `return 1 + left + right`?

Test case is

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

# [1, 2]
root = TreeNode(1)
root.left = TreeNode(2)

solution = Solution()
solution.minDepth(root)
```

My code returns `1` where it should return `2`.

**EDIT**
The depth of the tree is defined as the number of nodes in the shortest path from the root of the tree to a leaf node.

Comment: The main question is how do you define the minimum depth of a binary tree? Depending on that, different solutions are correct. If the path must end on a leaf node, then the correct answer is 2, otherwise it is 1. So, if that (ending on a leaf node) is requested, it has to be put into the code somehow.

Comment: Apologies for leaving out that information. So in my case, the depth of the tree is defined as the number of nodes in the shortest path from the root of the tree to a leaf node. However, what I do not understand is the value returned by the function. How one returned 1 and the other 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are at a node that has only one child, then in your first code version, the `min_depth` for that node will be 0 (since one of the recursive calls will return 0).

That is indeed wrong, because the node is not a leaf. It would only be correct if the node were a leaf (without children).

In your example, the root is such a node (with one child). This is what happens:

- `minDepth(root)` is called
- ....`minDepth(root.left)` is called
- ........`minDepth(root.left.left) is called and returns 0, because it is`None`
- ........`minDepth(root.left.right) is called and returns 0, because it is`None`
- ........`min_depth = min(left, right)` evaluates to 0
- ........the return value is 1 for `minDepth(root.left)`
- ....`minDepth(root.right)` is called and returns 0, because it is `None`
- ....`min_depth = min(left, right)` evaluates to 0, which is wrong.
- ....the final return value is thus 1 (wrong).

When you are in the situation where either `left` or `right` is 0, you need to get the `minDepth` of the remaining child and add 1 to it. That is why it works when you add this:

```
if left == 0 or right == 0:
    return 1 + left + right
```

Comment: thanks @trincot, but i think i am still confused (still new to the recursion concept here). my understanding is the stack will be [minDepth(1), minDepth(2)], and so, minDepth(2) will get executed first. then since, it's not `Null`, it would go to minDepth(2.left) (which returns 0) and minDepth(2.right) (which returns 0) the the `min_depth` will be 0, however in the return statement, it would be `return 1 + 0`, which is `1`. then when it calls minDepth(1), in the return statement it would be `return 1 + 1`, would it?

Comment: i think i just realised something. so the the value returned from calling `self.minDepth(2)` is `1` and `self.minDepth(1.right)` is `0`. then when it finally calls `self.minDepth(1)`, it would do `min_depth = min(1, 0)`, which is `0`. Thus, the final return statement is `return 1 + 0` which equates to `1` and hence why, my first code is wrong. gees, that 1 little detail. thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep, I had just added a paragraph listing the most important steps during the execution of your example.